# cannot convert from 'UnityEngine.Collider' to 'UnityEngine.Vector3

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

hi I'm trying to make the alien after seeing what tag the nearbyobjects have then move to it but i get this error

Assets\Scripts\AlienAI.cs(35,46): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'UnityEngine.Collider' to 'UnityEngine.Vector3'

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class AlienAI : MonoBehaviour
{
    public UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent myNavMeshAgent;
    public float Sight = 5.0f;
    public Transform Worker;

    [Header("Important")]
    public int Health;
    public Camera m_Camera;
    [SerializeField] string SoldierTag;
    [SerializeField] string WorkerTag;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        myNavMeshAgent = GetComponent<UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Collider[] colliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, Sight);
        foreach (Collider nearbyObjects in colliders)
        {
            if(nearbyObjects.tag == WorkerTag)
            {
               myNavMeshAgent.SetDestination(nearbyObjects);
            }
            if(nearbyObjects.tag == SoldierTag)
            {
               myNavMeshAgent.SetDestination(nearbyObjects);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I tried adding a .position but thats doesn't work

Comment: and it would be correct.. thats like do you want pizza or burgers.. "Yes" ...

Comment: take a look at the scripting reference for [Collider](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.html) for available members.

Answer (score 2):

The error occurs because `SetDestination()` takes a Vector3, while you are passing a Collider.
Assuming you want to set the destination to the position of the GameObject the Collider is attached to, you should instead do

```cs
myNavMeshAgent.SetDestination(nearbyObjects.transform.position);
```